# tabla html - varias filas en una columna

Tags: html, table, tr

Tengo una duda, cómo podría tener una tabla de este estilo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Teniendo una fila única que contenga las 3 filas internas, sin tener que tener que generar 3 filas o `<tr>` y estas vayan calzando en la columna correspondiente.

La idea es poder tener y ver la primera fila con sus filas internas de esta manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como una única fila y no separada en 3 o x `tr`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que tengo es este:

```css
table {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table th {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  padding: 0px 5px;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  padding: 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<table class='tbl'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Licitación</th>
      <th>Nombre Licitación</th>
      <th>Fecha Inicio</th>
      <th>Fecha Término</th>
      <th>Monto Tope</th>
      <th>Monto Ejecutado</th>
      <th>Estado Licitación</th>
      <th>Consumo</th>
      <th>Detalle</th>
      <th>Administrar</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class='FilaPrincipal' rowspan='3'>
      <td rowspan='3'>texto</td>
      <td rowspan='3'>texto</td>
      <td rowspan='1'>texto</td>
      <td rowspan='1'>texto</td>
      <td rowspan='1'>texto</td>
      <td rowspan='1'>texto</td>
      <td>texto</td>
      <td rowspan='3'>texto</td>
      <td rowspan='3'>texto</td>
      <td rowspan='3'>texto</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan='1'>texto</td>
      <td rowspan='1'>texto</td>
      <td rowspan='1'>texto</td>
      <td rowspan='1'>texto</td>
      <td rowspan='1'>texto</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan='1'>texto</td>
      <td rowspan='1'>texto</td>
      <td rowspan='1'>texto</td>
      <td rowspan='1'>texto</td>
      <td rowspan='1'>texto</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class='FilaPrincipal'>
      <td>texto 2</td>
      <td>texto 2</td>
      <td>texto 2</td>
      <td>texto 2</td>
      <td>texto 2</td>
      <td>texto 2</td>
      <td>texto 2</td>
      <td>texto 2</td>
      <td>texto 2</td>
      <td>texto 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

agradezco de antemano su ayuda

Comment: En el caso de que una celda contenga un texto muy largo, la solución que usas es la única forma (_según yo, ja_) donde las celdas hermanas a la fila se agrandarían automáticamente para igualar el alto. Cualquier otra forma tendrías que ver cómo acomodar las _"celdas en la misma fila"_ para igualar el alto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el caso de que el texto en las celdas no supere "un renglón", lo que podrías crear tablas dentro de las celdas donde van más de 1 "fila".

#### Ejemplo:

```css
table {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table th {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  padding: 0px 5px;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  padding: 5px 5px;
}

.conSubtabla {
  padding: 0;
  border-width: 0 1px;
}

.conSubtabla table {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.conSubtabla table td {
  border-width: 1px 0;
}
.conSubtabla table tr:first-child td {
  border-width: 0 0 1px;
}
.conSubtabla table tr:last-child td {
  border-width: 1px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<table class='tbl'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Licitación</th>
      <th>Nombre Licitación</th>
      <th>Fecha Inicio</th>
      <th>Fecha Término</th>
      <th>Monto Tope</th>
      <th>Monto Ejecutado</th>
      <th>Estado Licitación</th>
      <th>Consumo</th>
      <th>Detalle</th>
      <th>Administrar</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class='FilaPrincipal' rowspan='3'>
      <td>texto</td>
      <td>texto</td>
      <td class="conSubtabla">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Texto</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Texto</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Texto</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td class="conSubtabla">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Texto</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Texto</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Texto</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td class="conSubtabla">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Texto</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Texto</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Texto</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td class="conSubtabla">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Texto</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Texto</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Texto</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td class="conSubtabla">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Texto</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Texto</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Texto</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>texto</td>
      <td>texto</td>
      <td>texto</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='FilaPrincipal'>
      <td>texto 2</td>
      <td>texto 2</td>
      <td>texto 2</td>
      <td>texto 2</td>
      <td>texto 2</td>
      <td>texto 2</td>
      <td>texto 2</td>
      <td>texto 2</td>
      <td>texto 2</td>
      <td>texto 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Nota:** Esta solución no sirve cuando el alto de una celda es mayor al de las celdas "hermanas".

Comment: Muchas gracias, había intentado algo similar, pero era insertando la subtabla con todas las filas en la celda y esta no cuadraba con el header jajaja.

Answer (score 0):

Espero que esto pueda ser de ayuda

```
introducir el código aquí
<TABLE BORDER="1">
  <TR>
    <TH >
        Columna 1
    </TH>
    <TH >
        Columna 2
    </TH>
  </TR>
  <TR>
      <TD ROWSPAN="2">
        celda con dos filas
      </TD>
      <TD>
        celda de una fila 1
      </TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
      <TD>
        celda de una fila 2
      </TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
      <TD>
        celda de una fila 3
      </TD>
      <TD>
        celda de una fila 4
      </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente el funcionamiento del código. Lee [answer].

Comment: hola, aquí llegamos al mismo punto en el que me encuentro jaja